# DatePicker Validation - WinRT

Tags: validation, datepicker, windows-runtime

Hi I am developing a WinRT application, in which I am using DatePicker. I want to do DatePicker validation but could not find relevant listeners on it.

Only listener I  found was the datePicker_dateChanged which triggers when the date is changed.

I have two date pickers 'dpStartDate' and 'dpEndDate', My validation rules are 
dpStartDate can not be after dpEndDate
dpEndDate can not be before dpStartDate.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpStartDate " DateChanged="dpStartDate_DateChanged"  Header="End date" Margin="0,10,0,0"></DatePicker>
<DatePicker x:Name="dpEndDate" DateChanged="dpEndDate_DateChanged" Header="Start date" Margin="0,10,0,0"></DatePicker>

 private void dpStartDate_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dpEndDate_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Could you suggest how to do the validation.
If you can suggest of any other way for datePicker in WinRT that would be of great help.

Thanks in advance
Rao

Comment: Why not write code that checks the values when either changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building something like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        DateTimeOffset endDate;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DatePickerStart_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        if (DatePickerStart.Date > DatePickerEnd.Date)
        {
            DatePickerEnd.Date = DatePickerStart.Date;
            endDate = DatePickerEnd.Date;
        }
        }

        private void DatePickerEnd_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DatePickerStart.Date > DatePickerEnd.Date)
            {
                // Show message can't
                DatePickerEnd.Date = endDate;
            }
            else
            {
                endDate = DatePickerEnd.Date;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed,  I have already tried doing what you said but I got a errors regarding unhandled exception.
'Unhandled exception at 0x766D5388 (profapi.dll) in AppTesting.Windows.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x063E2EBC).'
I get unhandled exception when i try to change the start date.

Comment: I made 1 extra change and I am attaching the whole solution here for you: http://1drv.ms/22mupsu 
Which OS and VS versions are you using to build your app?